# Add selection on hidden element in Internet Explorer raise error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, range, microsoft-edge

I want to select a certain range on my webpage. If the element is hidden, IE (Internet Explorer) and Edge give an error. How can I add a selection to the document on a hidden element?

**Example**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style id="jsbin-css">
      #d2{
        display:none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="d1">div1</div>
    <div id="d2">div2</div>
    <div id="d3">div3</div>
    <a onclick="doSel()" href="javascript:void(0)">click me:)</a>
    <script id="jsbin-javascript">

    function doSel(){
    var element = $("#d2").contents()[0];
      var myRange = createRange(element,1, element,2);

      console.log(myRange);
      document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      document.getSelection().addRange(myRange);
    }

    function createRange(startContainer, startOffset, endContainer, endOffset){
        var rangeObj      = document.createRange ();

        rangeObj.setStart (startContainer, startOffset);
        rangeObj.setEnd (endContainer, endOffset);

        return rangeObj;
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

In this page I select the "i" in div#d2 in Firefox and Chrome, but IE gives me the error `unspecified error` and Edge gives me `Could not complete the operation due to error 800a025e.`. These errors are thrown at this line: `document.getSelection().addRange(myRange);`

How can I solve the problem and add a range to my document selection in IE and Edge?

Comment: @mplungjan I dit the search but didn't find any useful answers. the answers with `removeAllRanges()` were not working in my case. That is why I asked:)

Answer (score 2):

I did that search and couldn't find any explanation on why it errors.

A workaround, and becuase none of Chrome/FF return any value if the element has `display: none` (but Edge did), would be to actually check that first. And if it has `display:none`, pass an empty string back.

I also tried with below demo, if the element to grab had `display:none`, grab the previous and the next element.

With this I was actually able to grab the `display:none` element's text, though it only worked for IE11.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/p0k7jj12/2/

Part of the code for the quick test I did

```
function doSel(){

  var element3 = $("#d3").contents()[0];
  var element2 = $("#d2").contents()[0];
  var element1 = $("#d1").contents()[0];

  var myRange = createRange(element1,4, element3,0);

  console.log(myRange);
  document.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  document.getSelection().addRange(myRange);

  alert(document.getSelection());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer:D,
I looked at your fiddle and I must admit it is creative, but it selects the full content of the 2nd div and not one character as shown in my example. I did solve my problem another way actually. I wanted to wrap the selection and I can do that as well with :
`var a = $("<a />", {id: anchorId, "class": "noteElement"});
rangeObj.surroundContents(a[0]);`
First I wrapped all the selections in the document. Now I wrap a single element at a time.

Comment: The solution I provided is something to wrap a range without adding it to the document. It is not an answer for the question. The question is: how to add a range element to the document where the container is hidden. So I'm not sure to post it as a correct answer.